# How to compute multiple looping and if conditions for a Data Frame?

Tags: r, excel

I have a data like this below, and if you see the formula in excel, it compares the second element in row with the first element in the if statement and the loop goes on for next iterations.

I have pasted 6 rows here. Like this I have plenty of rows in my data frame. How to write the script for a situation like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This piece of code has solved my problem

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(df$Key[i]==df$Key[i+1] & df$Month_Year[i]==df$Month_Year[i+1]){
    df$Condition[i]="True"
  }else {
    df$Condition[i]="False"
  }
}


for(j in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(df$Condition[j]=="True"){
    if(df$Date[j]==df$Date[j+1]){
      df$Lead.Time[j]=0
    }else{
      df$Lead.Time[j]= df$Date[j+1]-df$Date[j]
    }
    
  }else {
    df$Lead.Time[j]=0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking if you can go through the rows of the data and check if every second element is equal to every first element?

If so the way that I would go about this programmatically is to loop through the rows in a step:

```
data=data.frame(Date=c(1,1,2,4,4),Time=c(2,2,3,4,4))
as_far_as=nrow(data)-1
for(i in 1:as_far_as){
     print(data$Date[i])
     print(data$Date[i+1])
 }
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 2
[1] 4
[1] 4
[1] 4
as_far_as=nrow(data)-1
for(i in 1:as_far_as){
    print(data$Date[i])
    print(data$Date[i+1])
}
```

Above I am looping through the rows and asking it to print every first element (`data$Date[i]`) and then every second element (`data$Date[i+1]`)

If I want to introduce boolean logic into this I would do:

```
as_far_as=nrow(data)-1
for(i in 1:as_far_as){
    if(data$Date[i]==data$Date[i+1] & data$time[i]==data$time[i+1]){
         print('dates are the same')
    }else{
         data$Date[i]=data$Date[i]-data$Date[i+1]
    }
}
```

I can't really get a sense of what exactly you're asking as I don't do excel but try playing with the code above and if statements `if(x==y){...}else{...}` to get what you want.

Comment: Hi, In the first iteration, 2nd element compared with 1st second iteration, 3rd element compared with 2nd element. And goes on.

Comment: yes this is how my code works: `for(i in 1:as_far_as){print(i);print(i+1)}` gives you `1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6.....`

Comment: Hi Cris, can you copy these data in a data frame and can you check if you are getting the output as I mentioned? In the lead time column you should have 2 values basically 6 and 4. Would be a great help mate.

Comment: Hi @Thinker I have put an example dataframe in my answer:
You will have to make an example dataframe for yourself with `data=data.frame(Data=c('30-01-09',...),Key=c('XYZ',...))`

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris